# How to sort an column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to open the demo.csv to convert it to an xlsx to sort column x, header name is called Birthplace, but I can't wrap my head around why the column doesn't want to sort.

Its does everything fine but doesn't sort the column.

```
import os
import time

from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

username = os.getenv("username")

filepath_in = Path(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\demo.csv').resolve()
filepath_out = Path(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\demo.xlsx').resolve()
pd.read_csv(filepath_in, delimiter=";").to_excel(filepath_out)

absolutePath = Path(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Downloads\\demo.xlsx').resolve()
os.system(f'start excel.exe "{absolutePath}"')

df = pd.read_excel(absolutePath)
print(df)
time.sleep(5)
df.sort_values(by='Birthplace',ascending=False, ignore_index=True).head()
print (df.sort_values)
```

Comment: Why do you think that the column doesn't get sorted?

Comment: `.sort_values()` returns a new dataframe. you will have to reassign `df`

Comment: When Excel opens with the demo.xlsx I don't see any adjustments or sorting happening :(

Comment: for the changes to take place on df, you have to add inplace=True to sort_values function.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the confusion. Pandas will read the CSV file but it will not automatically save the results. You will have to save the file explicitly using something like `df.to_excel` or `df.to_csv`.

As OP wrote in their question, one can sort the dataframe using `.sort_values()`, but it is important to keep in mind that this function returns a new dataframe. We need to reassign the output of `.sort_values()` to `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("demo.csv")
df = df.sort_values(by="Birthplace", ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
df.to_excel("demo.xlsx")
```

Once you save the file `demo.xlsx`, then you should see the sorted columns in Excel.